# Can I connect to an AP with Aircrack Suite and if yes how?

Tags: wireless-networking, bash, wireless-access-point, wpa2-psk, aircrack-ng

How can I connect to my WPA2 secured AP with aircrack suite?

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

(http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=newbie_guide#connecting_with_a_network)

> If you want to connect to a wireless network, there are some possibilities. In most cases, Open System Authentication is used. (Optional: If you want to learn more about authentication, check this out.)
>
> Open System Authentication:
>
> Ask the AP for authentication.
>
> The AP answers: OK, you are authenticated.
>
> Ask the AP for association
>
> The AP answers: OK, you are now connected.

Comment: I found this on their homepage, too thanks. But I would need a practical example.